# Multiple set-cookie header in personalized page

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, java

We have a little problem with the personalization module in the SDL Tridion 2011 and we are not sure if it is a bug, problem with the configuration of the cd_wai in our Linux presentation server (Java implementation) or not an issue or all.

We present a "personalized" page depending on a customer characteristic (user country). We show different component presentations depending from which country is the user accessing to the page.

Apparently it works smooth, but if we use a tool for sniffing the HTTP headers in the response when a user request for this page, we can see that the (same) header "Set-Cookie" is set a lot of times (varying based on the number of component presentations that do not match with the first component presentation mapped to the user's country.)

Have any of you experienced something like this?

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange! I have edited your post slightly to hopefully clarify and improve it. If you don't agree with my edits please feel free to revert them back to your original posting.

Answer (score 5):

There is a known defect with WAI and 2011 SP1.  Multiple cookies are set per session for each page requested that has PnP enabled on it.  It should be one cookie per session.  This defect has a Hotfix for it on top of 2011 SP1 + HR1, CD_2011.1.1.79834.  It is at Tridion World here:

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx

It is also fixed with 2011 SP1 + Hotfix Rollup #2.

Answer (score 2):

I've only set up P&P to try it out, but per [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_5FBF48D998A84C36AE0AB629623C6752) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)), Each "Component Presentation with one or more associated Target Groups will check the visitor who is requesting the Page."

The [Target Group Personalization TBB](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-359791056) that's part of the Default Finish Actions should automatically handle adding tracking in the form of TCDL tags. I could be wrong, but I'm reading this to mean Component Presentations without Target Groups wouldn't have the TCDL.

I believe cookies are also used for tracking. There are options to [exclude certain pages or paths](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_9A404F37534F49D289C95CD16E7F7F1F), but are you experiencing an actual visitor issue?

I'd recommend:

1. Double check your "non-personalized" CPs don't have target groups.
2. See if the cookies are related to tracking (and if that's really an issue).

Comment: Even we have all the tracking (for components/pages,...) disabled, the problem remains. Regarding to the point 1. we have checked that all the CPs has assigned one or more target groups.

Comment: So each CP seems to be *setting* a cookie, but I think you're expecting it to only set a cookie "as needed?" I'm not sure if that's necessarily an issue. Maybe check with Support. I'll ask around if anyone knows how the "check the visitor" logic works in delivery.